# Left half open topology

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

Given the topology $\tau$ on X= $\mathbb{R}$, which contains all sets $(a,b]$ with a,b$\in\mathbb{R}$, $a<b$, show that the intervals $(a,b), (a, \infty)$ and $(-\infty,b]$ are also in $\tau$.

Can I say that $(-\infty, b]\cap (a,\infty)=(a,b]$ and thus they are in $\tau$?  Or would one rather construct an infinite union such as $\bigcup_{i \in \mathbb{N}} A_i$ where $A_i=(a, b+i]$ which is open in $\tau$.

How would one formally show that $[a,b)$ is not open in $\tau$ because it cannot be expressed as a union or intersection of open intervals?

I greatly appreciate help with these rather 'easy' topology questions since it's the first week of the topic and I am not yet familiar with it.

Comment: Prove and use that $(0,1)=\bigcup\limits_{n\in\mathbb{N}}[1/n,1)$

Comment: You definitely can't conclude that $\{b\}$ is open. Why would you think you could? If $\{b\}$ is open for all $b,$ then every set would be open, and you'd have the "discrete topology."

Comment: For the question about $[a,b)$ first note that a finite intersection of sets of the form $(x,y]$ is either empty or a set of the form $(x,y].$ So every open set in $\tau$ is a union of sets of the form $(x,y].$ Now if $[a,b)$ is open...

Answer (score 2):

$$(a,b)=\bigcup_{x \in (a,b)} (a,x]$$

$$(a,+\infty) = \bigcup_{x > a} (a,x]$$

$$(-\infty, b] = \bigcup_{x < b} (x,b]$$

shows that all those types of intervals can be written as unions of basic open sets, and thus are open too.

Answer (score 0):

We have that $\forall n \in \mathbb{N}/\{1\}$ the subset $(a,b-(b-a)/n]$ is open so $\cup_{n \in \mathbb{N}/\{1\}} (a,b-(b-a)/n] = (a,b)$ is open.

We have that $\forall n \in \mathbb{N} ,(a,b+n]$ is open so $(a,+ \infty)= \cup_{n \in \mathbb{N}} (a,b+n]$ is open.

We have that $\forall n \in \mathbb{N}, (a-n,b]$ is open so $(- \infty, b]= \cup_{n \in \mathbb{N}} (a-n,b]$ is open.